# how to properly read path parameter from url in flutter web

Tags: flutter

I'm accessing username from the url and querying data of that username from firebase

For example, if link structure is like this [www.example.com/john](http://www.example.com/john), I access 'john' from it which works perfectly

For that, I'm using URI package

Uri.base.pathSegments[0] // returns john

but it throws the following error with it when I open the url

```
RemoteDebuggerExecutionContext: Timed out finding an execution context after 100 ms.
RemoteDebuggerExecutionContext: Timed out finding an execution context after 100 ms.
AppInspector: Missing execution context ID: Error: Bad state: No context with the running Dart application.

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
          child: StreamBuilder(
            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('User').where('username', isEqualTo: Uri.base.pathSegments[0]).snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot){
              if(snapshot.hasData){
                BioModel bioModel = BioModel.fromMap(snapshot.data!.docs[0].data());
                return Column();
              }
              return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(color: Color(0xff16083A)));
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```